# addAttributeToSort by ASC ignore null values

Tags: magento-1.7, product, database, product-list

I am  try to sort my product collection.

At first it should be sorted by alphabet (A,B,C..) and then by other character like NULL ...

This is my code which I have tried...

```
return $this->_productCollection
        //->addAttributeToFilter('hero', array('FIND_IN_SET'=>array('A','',NULL)))
        //->getSelect()->order("FIND_IN_SET(hero,'A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q,R,S,T,U,V,W,X,Y,Z') DESC")
        //->addOrder("FIND_IN_SET(hero,'A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q,R,S,T,U,V,W,X,Y,Z') DESC, hero, NULL")
        //->addAttributeToSort("FIELD(hero,'A,, ')", 'ASC')
        ->addAttributeToSort('hero', 'DESC')
        //->addAttributeToFilter('hero', 'notnull')
        ;
```

Answer (score 1):

please follow the code

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
             ->addAttributeToSort('field', 'ASC')
             ->getSelect()
             ->reset('order')
             ->order('isnull(`field`), `field` ASC');
```

where $product got sorted value.

Comment: Where you have added this code can you explain me please??

Comment: showing  Unknown column 'isnull('fieldname')

Comment: How can i use it in Magento 2